# What is meant by "Top-End" and "Bottom-End"?

Tags: guitar, terminology, acoustics

When guitarists describe the sound of their guitars, a lot of terms are used.

What does a guitarist mean when they talk about top and bottom end?

Comment: Probably a great example of bottom-end is Spinal Tap's "Big Bottom", which has dual lead bass lines. :-)

Comment: There are several versions on the YouTube. It's a tongue-in-cheek song, in the typical crude Spinal Tap style. Oh, it's three basses, one of which is a double-neck. They were having some fun when they filmed that song.

Comment: I'll also recommend "Boris the Spider", by John Entwhistle, and almost any song Chris Squire is on with Yes. Both are well recognized for super-clean, high-fidelity, solid bass sound.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Top end refers to the treble tones on your guitar and bottom end refers to the bass tones; these are also referred to as 'highs' and 'lows'; and can be adjusted using the EQ on your amp.

Comment: Not just the EQ on your amp is used to adjust this. Pedals, rack mount equalizers, and even different guitars will affect these parameters.

Comment: Of course; EQ can be applied anywhere in the signal path, or at any time during production.  The EQ on the amp however is your first stop for your playing tone.

Comment: The tone control on your guitar is the first stop, for those guitars with them.

Comment: @the Tin Man: good point

Answer (score 1):

DRL's right but, just for completeness, some occassionally use it to describe the overall quality of the sound.  "It's a low-end guitar but it sounds top-end," etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this usage is usually "low-end" vs. "high-end," as opposed to top and bottom being asked about here.

Comment: I've heard both, but low- and high-end are definitely more common.

Answer (score 0):

Low End = bass

Top End = treble  (high end, etc.)

The terms describe the frequency domain of a tone.